# V/SprdCameraHardware: isCapturing: SPRD_WAITING_JPEG

Tags: java, android, camera, android-camera, samsung-mobile

Debugging an Android application on the following Samsung device `Samsung SM-G355H Galaxy Core 2 Duos` I see multiple lines in the logcat same as the title.

```
..
V/SprdCameraHardware: isCapturing: SPRD_WAITING_JPEG
V/SprdCameraHardware: isCapturing: SPRD_WAITING_JPEG
V/SprdCameraHardware: isCapturing: SPRD_WAITING_JPEG
..
```

And gets stuck so until the OS reports it as not responding. Upon killing the app (either from the apps or pressing OK on the pop-up "Not Responding.."-dialog), it keeps the Camera resource and prevents subsequent use. Even though I release it at both the `onPause` and `onStop` of the respective activity. It is not releasing it, because it continues to *capture* with the same exact message in logcat: `V/SprdCameraHardware: isCapturing: SPRD_WAITING_JPEG`.

On the emulator or other Samsung specs works just fine.

Any clarifications would be gladly welcomed. Thanks.